# Drupal 8 Menu Item child of a Task

Tags: drupal-8

For my custom Drupal 8 (8.7.8) module, I have the following ...

```
my_module.reports:
  route_name: my_module.reports
  title: 'Reports'
  base_route: my_module.dashboard
  weight: 80
```

in my menu system in my_module.links.menu.yml and it appears as a tab on my dashboard I'm building. On that page, the route controller I have is...

```
_controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
```

I'm hoping to make there a list of further links to reports. But this (from my_module.links.menu.yml) ...

```
my_module.reports.territories:
  title: 'Territories'
  description: '...'
  route_name: my_module.reports.territories
  parent: my_module.reports
  weight: 10
```

Doesn't show up. All I get when I go to that page is: 
"You do not have any administrative items."

What am I missing? Is it somehow not possible to make children of tasks in this way or is this something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked it out. I had to ALSO add ...

```
my_module.reports:
  title: 'Reports'
  parent: system.admin_config
  route_name: my_module.reports
```

... to my_module.links.menu.yml. I could then leave the link in my_module.links.task.yml as well to create the final thing I wanted.